# Java + how to read MS SQL DB bak file

Tags: java, sql-server

I read & create MS SQL server created bak file in java. But for this prediction is MS sql server is not installed on that machine.
Are there any tool / library with the help of that I can read/ write file?

Comment: the file suffix bak normally denotes a backup file. IS an MS Sql bak file something different? What is in the file, what is it's structure?

Comment: when I opened bak file its in binary format. I tried one more to read  & write db mdb file created in MS ACCESS through Java. I want it in same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tool that can read `.bak` files that I'm aware of (except SQL Server, of course) is Red Gate's SQL Compare. [Apparently the Pro Version can read data from `.bak` files.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/features)

But this is a commercial tool, so you have to buy and install it.
And since you have to install something anyway, why not just install the free SQL Server Express Edition? It can read `.bak` files too, and it's free.

Comment: Note that the tools that 'read' .bak files do so via a SQL Server instance. They expose the .bak file as a virtual device and attach the database on this 'device'. Is still SQL Server that really reads the file.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know this. I only knew that SQL Compare is able to read `.bak` files, but I wasn't aware that it does so by using SQL Server. So there's no way to avoid installing SQL Server.